# 3D Stacked Column Chart using js libraries

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts

We're working on converting a business functionality currently performed using Excel to AngularJS.

First image below can be produced rather effortlessly using Excel. We've been having a very hard time trying to produce the same using js libraries. Our devs have tried highcharts and d3 without much success. The issue is, adding the 3D effect to stacked column chart.

I looked at [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-stacked-column-chart/) but not the same as what our business wants.

Is js not the right tool to produce this simple business chart? Has anyone been successful in producing something similar using js libraries?

**Produced using Excel**

[image]

**Produced using HighCharts.js**

[image]

Comment: I was directed to a collection of Javascript-based data visualization libraries that may be helpful for you and your team in your research: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/javascript-graphs-and-charts-libraries. Speaking from my Highcharts experience, there are ways to adjust the view and dimensions of your columns, but some properties in column charts, such as borders, rounded corners, and shadows, are ignored in the 3D view.

Comment: For now it is not possible to make your chart with standard Highcharts functions. If you think it is good idea to have this functionality in Highcharts, you can ask for it on uservoice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/